# How to make new line in js var array value

Tags: javascript

I have code like this, I just want to make my marker info which have a new line in info window, something like

```
  first line 
  second line
  etc
```

but with variable like this, how can I make new line with my code like this?

```
 function addMarker(marker) {
      var category = marker[2];
      var title = marker[9];
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[10], marker[11]);
      var content = marker[3] +  marker[9] + marker[8];
      var session = marker[6];
      var myIcon='http://ruralshores.com/assets/marker-icon.png'; 
      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: title,
          position: pos,
          category: category,
          session: session,
          map: map,
          icon: myIcon 
      });
```

How can I make new line on my code?

```
var content = marker[3] +  marker[9] + marker[8];
```

Comment: Did you try `\n`?

Comment: I've tried it, but not worked

Comment: Don't know about maps Markers, but it might be parsing an HTML string rather than just plain text, in which case `<br>` might be needed

Comment: If you mean displaying a new line in html, then add '<br>'.

Comment: Sounds like when you tried `\n` you didn't understand to treat it like any two characters in a string. See my example.

Comment: Are you trying to display that code in an HTML page (similar to what you see here)?

Answer (score 0):

Googling "javascript new line in string" reveals any number of links with the answer.

JS uses the character combination '\n' for a new line. Just put it in your string as you would any characters. Here's an example:

```js
var x = ['A','B','C'];

alert(x[0] + '\n' + x[1] + '\n' + x[2]);
```

Comment: He tried that, didn't work. I'm guessing it needs to be HTML instead.

Comment: thanks for answering my ask, but i mean i want to make a new line with my code like this var content = marker[3] +  marker[9] + marker[8];

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm guessing he didn't realize that he needed to enclose it in quotes. Of course, we're both guessing, because he used the forbidden term "didn't work." :)

Comment: how i can make new line from var array like that?

Comment: @Kraken I believe my edits are what you're looking for. Is that correct? Or are you saying that you want each array element to automatically have a new line in it?

Comment: yes i want my var array, var content = marker[3] +  marker[9] + marker[8]; have a new line from each array elemen

Comment: seem the output like,
marker[3]
marker[9]
marker[8]
with the new line in every next  marker

Comment: @Kraken Ok, look at my example. I've set up `x[1]` that way (assigned the value `'b\n'`). When you're assigning the string value to the array element, tack on a `\n` at the end. (The n stands for new line.)

Comment: can you give me example from my variable var content = marker[3] +  marker[9] + marker[8];

Comment: @kraken I'm sorry, I'm not going to do that. I'm trying to teach you how to do it, not do it for you. I will simplify my example, though. Substitute your `marker` array in your mind for the `x` array in my example and figure it out.

Comment: thanks for teach me :), this my solved code  var content = (marker['3'] + '<br/>' + marker['9'] +  '<br/>' +marker['8']);

Comment: @Kraken You're welcome. Why did you use `<br/>` instead of `\n`? (And it wasn't me. I don't downvote people except sometimes when they give answers that are obviously wrong.)